# Arduino only addresses 3 LED at a time

Tags: neopixel

I am running the following sketch on an Arduino Uno using Arduino 1.6.8.
Strip is a WS2811 12V.

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#define PIN 6
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(30, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  strip.begin();
  strip.show();
}

void loop (){
   strip.setPixelColor(0, 255, 0, 255);
   strip.show(); 
}
```

The problem is that the LED’s light in (Green) groups of three and what I want is individual control.

```
strip.setPixelColor(0, 255, 0, 255); Illuminates Pixels 0,1,2
strip.setPixelColor(1, 255, 0, 255); Illuminates Pixels 3,4,5
strip.setPixelColor(2, 255, 0, 255); Illuminates Pixels 6,7,8
```

And so forth.

Although this code uses NeoPixel I get exactly the same issue if I use the equivalent in FastLed.

Any pointers to what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

LED strips with WS2811 and 12V are the ones with one driver and 3 RGB LEDs on it. These are interconnected so you just can't control less than whole group of three.

If you need individual control, you have to get 5V variant with [WS2812](http://www.tme.eu/gb/details/hc-f5v-30l-30_20/light-sources-led-ribbon/worldsemi/hc-f5v-30l-30led-wip20/).